# issue rotating bitmap shader

Tags: android, rotation, android-canvas

I am drawing a path on a canvas with canvas.drawPath using a paint instance which had previously been set up with a bitmapShader. I see this bitmap as the skin of the animation
element.
The problem is that I need to move the path around the screen, rotate it and scale it.
My problem is that when ROTATION is involved the shader becomes pixellated.

Is there any way to prevent this or improve it ?

Thanks,